# Freezing Function Arguments

Tags: python, function, object, operator-overloading, decorator

I am trying to write a class that gives the functionality of the input function, but remembers the arguments from last call and will only update them like a dictionary. I have this so far but I would love to know if there is a better way:

```
class freezefunc:
    def __init__(self, func, **funcargs):
        self.func = func
        self.funcargs = {}

    def call(self, **kwargs):
        self.funcargs.update(kwargs)
        self.func(**self.funcargs)
```

So this works like this then:

```
def func(a):
    print a
frozenfunc = freezefunc(func)
frozenfunc.call(a='somevalue')
```

prints: somevalue

```
frozenfunc.call(a='theupdatedvalue')
```

prints: theupdatedvalue

Is there something like this that I just haven't found?

UPDATDE: the function [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from the library [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) performs very much the same task.

Comment: in case anyone has suggestions to improve the title or tags for this question, to make it more usefull  I am thankful for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special method `__call__` lets you call `frozenfunc`, directly:

```
class freezefunc:
    def __init__(self, func, **funcargs):
        self.func = func
        self.funcargs = {}

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        self.funcargs.update(kwargs)
        return self.func(**self.funcargs)

def func(a):
    print(a)
```

Now:

```
frozenfunc = freezefunc(func)
frozenfunc(a='somevalue')
```

prints:

```
somevalue
```

and:

```
frozenfunc(a='theupdatedvalue')
```

prints:

```
theupdatedvalue
```

Comment: Yes, operator overloading (what this is often called) is nice. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I just realized that if i don't add a return before the self.func(**self.funcargs) it does not work. Why is that? Because the return statement one returns to the ´__call__´ method?

Comment: yip looks like it the case of using print is a bi deciving here